# How to generate a sitemap ?(asp.net mvc3)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, menu, sitemap

This is my database table

[DB Table](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Sql2Tree-SQL-table-data.png)

how to generate a sitemap?

controller is category

action is Id

that is look like it

[Page](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Sql2Tree-HTML-nested-list.png)

---

TreeMenu.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Pmvc.Models
{
    public partial class TreeMenu
    {
        public int TreeId { get; set; }
        public int TreeParentId { get; set; }
        public string TreeName { get; set; }
        public List<TreeMenu> Children { get; set; }
    }

}
```

StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MvcSiteMapProvider.Extensibility;
using Pmvc.Models;


namespace Pmvc
{
    public class StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
    {
        PMVCEntities pmvcDB = new PMVCEntities();
        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {

            var nodes = new List<DynamicNode>();

            foreach (var treemenu in pmvcDB.TreeMenu)
            {
                nodes.Add(CreateNode(treemenu));
            }

            return nodes;
        }

        private DynamicNode CreateNode(TreeMenu treemenu)
        {

            DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
            node.Action = "ProductDetails";
            node.Controller = "Product";
            node.Title = treemenu.TreeName;

            if (treemenu.Children != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in treemenu.Children)
                {
                    node.Children.Add(CreateNode(child)); //This line is wrong!
                }
            }
            return node;

        }

    }


}
```

wrong:

'MvcSiteMapProvider.Extensibility.DynamicNode' is not include 'Children' definition，and not find Extension Methods 'Children'

---

```
public class StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
    {
        PMVCEntities pmvcDB = new PMVCEntities();
        public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection()
        {
            // Build value 
            var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

            // Create a node for each album 
            foreach (var treemenu in pmvcDB.TreeMenu)
            {
                DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();
                node.Action = "ProductDetails";
                node.Controller = "Product";
                node.Title = treemenu.TreeName;
                node.RouteValues.Add("id", treemenu.TreeId);
                returnValue.Add(node);
            }

            // Return 
            return returnValue;
        } 
    }
```

This is my table

TreeId TreeParentId TreeName

1   0   Category 1

2   1   Menu Item X

3   1   Menu Item Y

4   1   Menu Item Z

5   0   Category 2

6   5   Other Menu 1

7   5   Other Menu 2

8   0   Empty Category

9   7   Menu Lvl 3

How do I write child node code?

Comment: Many SO contributors dislike writing the code for the posters: it is a programming Q&A site, not an outsourcing one... Did you tried something? BTW, you should have posted your table content and expected result as text.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [MvcSitemap provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki).  It's pretty easy to write a [dynamic provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Dynamic-sitemaps) that reads from your database.

Edit - did you read the documentation or attempt to implement anything?  Copied almost verbatim from their site:

Within the sitemap config file, add the dynamic node where appropriate:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode 
    title="Details" 
    action="Details"   
    dynamicNodeProvider="MyProjectName.MyDynamicNodeProvider, MyProjectName" />
```

Then, write the actual node provider:

```
public class MyDynamicNodeProvider
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection() 
    {
        // Build value 
        var returnValue = new List<DynamicNode>();

        // ... Here, get values from your database and build up
        // the list of nodes.  They can be in a tree structure
        // too since it appears that's how your data is - just
        // build the nodes in that way with sub-lists.

        // Return 
        return returnValue; 
    } 
}
```

And that's it.

Edit 2 - addressing other answer.

The code that you provided flattens the tree structure.  In your original post you showed that you are already able to [print the tree structure](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Sql2Tree-HTML-nested-list.png).  Whatever code you had in your view, you can apply the same principles of a depth-first traversal.

Just in case that was a mockup and not actual code, here's some quick psuedo code to demonstrate an depth-first traversal.

```
public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection() 
{
    // Build value 
    var nodes = new List<DynamicNode>();

    // Get all categories without parents.
    var rootCategories = db.GetRootCategories();  

    // Loop all root level categories, creating a node for each and adding
    // to the return value.
    foreach (var category in rootCategories)
    {
        nodes.Add(CreateNode(category));
    }
    return nodes;
}

private DynamicNode CreateNode(Category category)
{
    // Create a new node for the category
    DynamicNode node = new DynamicNode();

    node.Name = category.Name;
    // ... set node properties here ...

    // If the category has children, then continue down the tree
    // and create nodes for them.  This will continue recursively
    // to the bottom of the tree.
    // Note that I'm just guessing on the property names because
    // you didn't show us the code for what your entity actually
    // looks like.  This is why you should always show what code
    // you've attempted - you can get better, more precise answers
    // instead of complete guesses.
    if (category.Children != null)
    {
        foreach (var child in category.Children)
        {
            // For each child, recursively branch into them.
            node.Children.Add(CreateNode(child));
        }
    }

    return Node;
}
```

Please note that this is no way tested or researched - it's only to show a tree traversal.

Comment: How do I add a child node in a parent node ?

use the Dynamic sitemaps ?